# Gutenberg Shortcode will turn html to html entity

Tags: shortcode, block-editor

I defined a shortcode `[plot]` to write `dot` code. For example, I insert code below by using Gutenberg Shortcode:

```
[plot]
digraph G {
a->b;
}
[/plot]
```

But when I re-edit the code, it will be converted to:

```
[plot]
digraph G {
a-&gt;b
}
[/plot]
```

`>` will be converted to `&gt;`, it is difficult to copy `dot` code for debug.So, how to prevent the convert?

Comment: Have you considered building a block instead?

Comment: @TomJNowell Yes, I am learning how to write a block plugin. It is a little difficult for me.